Question about red and blue balls in boxes
I am looking at the following question:
"Some red balls and blue balls are distributed among 99 boxes. Your task is to choose 50 of the boxes in such a way that you have claimed at least half of the balls of each colour. Can you always do this, no matter how many balls there are or how they are distributed?"
I suspect the answer to this question is yes, however I am having some difficulty showing this formally. Any help with this question would be very much appreciated.

Please edit to include your efforts.  To start, I suggest working this out for numbers smaller than $99$.  I figure "odd" might be relevant so start with $3$ or $5$ and work from there.

Worth clarifying whether you can see into the boxes... like, if all balls are placed into a single box but you don't know which one it is... then the answer is definitely no. I'm assuming the question is asking, though, whether this is always doable with the condition that you can see into the boxes, though.

That's correct yes, you can see into each box.
